# What is the purpose of # in antlr grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a statement in an ANTLR4 grammar like:

```
expression : DEFAULT    #primitive_expression
           ;
```

I don't know what is the meaning of `#` here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're *alternative labels*:

> **Alternative Labels**
>
> As we saw in Section 7.4, Labeling Rule Alternatives for Precise Event Methods, we can get more precise parse-tree listener events by labeling the outermost alternatives of a rule using the # operator. All alternatives within a rule must be labeled, or none of them. Here are two rules with labeled alternatives.
>
> ```
> grammar T;
> stat: 'return' e ';' # Return
>   | 'break' ';' # Break
>   ;
> e   : e '*' e # Mult
>     | e '+' e # Add
>     | INT # Int
>     ;
> ```
>
> Alternative labels do not have to be at the end of the line and there does not have to be a space after the # symbol. ANTLR generates a rule context class definition for each label. For example, here is the listener that ANTLR generates:
>
> ```
> public interface AListener extends ParseTreeListener {
>   void enterReturn(AParser.ReturnContext ctx);
>   void exitReturn(AParser.ReturnContext ctx);
>   void enterBreak(AParser.BreakContext ctx);
>   void exitBreak(AParser.BreakContext ctx);
>   void enterMult(AParser.MultContext ctx);
>   void exitMult(AParser.MultContext ctx);
>   void enterAdd(AParser.AddContext ctx);
>   void exitAdd(AParser.AddContext ctx);
>   void enterInt(AParser.IntContext ctx);
>   void exitInt(AParser.IntContext ctx);
> }
> ```

From: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels

Comment: I think I made an erroneous edit to your post.  How can I delete it?

Comment: I already rejected it, and I don't think someone else will approve it.